# Document not being replaced on DocumentDb

Tags: azure, f#, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure's `DocumentDb` with F#, and I've been able to create new documents, load all documents, and load a document by an Id, with a `where` filter applied. But I can't replace any documents, and there is very little documentation out there in F#.

This is the function I am using to update a document:

```
let update (c : MyObject) =
    let cli = createClient()
    cli.ReplaceDocumentAsync(documentUri(), c)
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> ignore
    c
```

`createClient` simply creates a new instance of a `DocumentClient`, with the same arguments that let me load & save new documents. Similarly, `documentUri()` works in other functions.

My  *guess* is that I'm actually getting a useful response out of the task, which I'm ignoring (based on examples I've seen). However, trying to get that response is proving difficult.

This is a method I tried to get working, but ended up with a type that I couldn't seem to cast:

```
let update2 ( c : MyObject) =
    let cli = createClient()
    let updatedDoc = async {
        return! cli.ReplaceDocumentAsync(documentUri(), c) |> Async.AwaitTask
    }
    updatedDoc
```

Here, `updatedDoc` is of type `Async<ResourceResponse<Document>>`. I can't seem to find a way to get it out of the `Async` wrapper, and once I do I'm not sure how I turn the `Document` into `MyObject`.

So, in summary:

- The issue is that I am unable to update documents
- I suspect I'm getting an error message or something out of the Task that I'm ignoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# `async` computations are different from C# `Task`s in that they are not executed right on the spot. Simply creating an `async` computation does nothing:

```
let x = async { printfn "Foo!" }  // No output is generated here
```

In order to actually run it, you need to specify *how* to run it: schedule it on a thread pool, run synchronously on the current thread, convert into a `Task`, etc. For example:

```
let x = async { printfn "Foo!" }
Async.RunSynchronously x // Prints "Foo!"
```

Alternatively, one can "run" an async computation by including it in another async computation, which is itself then executed in some way:

```
let y = async {
     do! x
     printfn "Bar!"
   }

Async.RunSynchronously y  // Prints "Foo!" and then "Bar!"
```

So, in order to execute your second example (and hopefully see the returned error), you need to actually *run* the resulting workflow:

```
let update2 ( c : MyObject) =
    let cli = createClient()
    let updateDoc = cli.ReplaceDocumentAsync(documentUri(), c) |> Async.AwaitTask
    Async.RunSynchronously updateDoc
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew they were different, but my C# experience made me wary of a `RunSynchronously` command. In the context you gave it makes more sense. I was able to get a confusing error, resolve that, and now I can update documents. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.